# Python code for REST calls with cookiejar file

Tags: python, rest, curl, httplib, cookiejar

I use following curl commands to fetch data using cookiejar file:

```
$ curl -sk -X 'POST' -d "username=name@domain.com&password=mypassword" -c app.cookie-jar -k https://website.com/auth/authenticate
$ curl -sk -X 'GET' -H 'Accept: text/csv' -b app.cookie-jar https://website.com/api/systems > out.csv
```

Can someone help with python script that can help in achieving the same

Comment: Do you actually need a cookie jar file, or do you just need an HTTP session that keeps track of cookies in-memory?

Comment: Either option is fine with me, as long as I can fetch the data, as shown in second curl command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/), set up a session to keep track of the cookie:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    resp = s.post('https://website.com/auth/authenticate', data='username=name@domain.com&password=mypassword')
    resp.raise_for_status()
    resp = s.get('https://website.com/api/systems', headers={'Accept': 'text/csv'})
    resp.raise_for_status()
    with open('out.csv', 'wb') as outf:
        outf.write(resp.content)
```

Comment: You may want to try `data={'username': 'name@domain.com', 'password': 'mypassword'}` instead, depending on how the API expects to receive the login.

Comment: Great help AKX ! It worked ! Thank you so much for your quick response.
```
$ 
$ cat test.py
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    resp = s.post('https://website.com/auth/authenticate',  data={'username': 'name@domain.com', 'password': 'mypassword'})
    resp.raise_for_status()
    resp = s.get('https://website.com/api/systems', headers={'Accept': 'text/csv'})
    resp.raise_for_status()
    with open('out.csv', 'wb') as outf:
        outf.write(resp.content)
$
$ python test.py
$ ls -l out.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 username eng 2764 Feb 20 06:39 out.csv
$
```